# R name column when creating data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, creation

I'm taking the columns from a data frame and using them to create another data frame, but the names keep getting jumbled instead of keeping the original name.  How do I avoid this?

```
> newDigit1 <- data.frame((security_id = rsPred1$security_id))
> head(newDigit1)
  X.security_id...rsPred1.security_id.
1                                    1
2                                    6
3                                    5
4                                    3
5                                    3
6                                    2
```

It should be like this:

```
> newDigit1 <- data.frame((security_id = rsPred1$security_id))
> head(newDigit1)
                                security_id
1                                    1
2                                    6
3                                    5
4                                    3
5                                    3
6                                    2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you've doubled up the brackets `((`.
Compare

```
dfr <- data.frame(x = 1:5)
#Case 1
data.frame(x = dfr$x)
#Case 2
data.frame((x = dfr$x))
```

In case 1, `x = dfr$x` is a name-value pair being passed into the `data.frame` function.

In case 2, `(x = dfr$x)` returns a vector with no name, so R invents a temporary one and  then passes that vector into the `data.frame` function.

Answer (score 4):

When you create your data frame, don't have the double brackets:

```
newDigit1 <- data.frame(security_id = rsPred1$security_id)
```

Not

```
newDigit1 <- data.frame((security_id = rsPred1$security_id))
```

Answer (score 2):

simply remove one bracket:

```
newDigit1 <- data.frame(security_id = rsPred1$security_id)
```

should be working now!